# Could someone explain this PHP syntax?

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to patch a bit of PHP in a rather large and complex WordPress theme, and I found this line:

```
if(is_array($taxonomys)) {
    $tax = 1;
    foreach ($taxonomys as $key => $value ) {

        if($taxonomys[$key]->parent == 0 && isset($taxonomys[$key]->name) && in_array($taxonomys[$key]->name, $used_taxonomys)) {
            echo '<li class="tab"><li class="selected"><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">'.lambda_translate_meta($taxonomys[$key]->name).'</a></h3></li>';
        } 
        if(in_array($taxonomys[$key]->name, $used_taxonomys) && $taxonomys[$key]->parent != 0 ) {                           
            echo '<li class="tab"><h3><a href="#" data-filter=".'.$taxonomys[$key]->slug.'_filt">'.lambda_translate_meta($taxonomys[$key]->name).'</a></h3></li>';
        }
    $tax++;
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain the -> and => syntax? [Google](https://www.google.ca/?q=PHP+syntax+%22-%3E%22#safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=PHP+syntax+%22-%3E%22&oq=PHP+syntax+%22-%3E%22&gs_l=hp.3...0.0.1.2468.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.ernk_timediscountc..0.0...1..17.hp.zChabTgNFTg&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.dmg&fp=ad2e1547bf86af39&biw=1527&bih=842) is surprisingly unhelpful.

As a side note, if anyone would also offer there ideas about what the if statements are about, I would be incredibly grateful.

Comment: This really is basic PHP which is handled perfectly fine by reading the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php and http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php in general

Comment: You can replace all occurrences of `$taxonomys[$key]` with `$value`.

Comment: Besides Google, there is also Symbolhound for searching source code tokens, http://symbolhound.com/?q=php+what+does+%3D%3E++mean%3F

Comment: Upon reflection this question ought to be closed as a duplicate of several other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($taxonomys as $key => $value ) {
```

This loops through each element in the `$taxonomys` array, assigning the key to `$key`, and the value to `$value`.  This array is a associative array where values have specific keys, not necessarily numeric keys.

```
$taxonomys[$key]->parent
```

The `->` gets you the property of the object.  The object in this case is `$taxonomys[$key]`, and the property they want is `parent`.  Note that they could have also just used `$value->parent`, since due to the foreach loop, `$value` is the same as `$taxonomys[$key]`.

Answer (score 1):

-> is used to indicate a method or property of an object

=> is used either to initialise a key/value pair in an array or, as in this case, to extract the key/value pair in a foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

`->` denotes accessing a property or method of an object.

`=>` is generally used to defined `array('key' => 'value')` pairs in an array. The foreach case is special and it just means that the code inside of the foreach block will be executed once for each element in the `$taxonomys` array and the element key will be available in the `$key` variable and the value in the `$value` variable.